# Let us deal cunningly with them

Tags: torah-study

הָבָה נִתְחַכְּמָה לוֹ פֶּן־יִרְבֶּה וְהָיָה כִּי־תִקְרֶאנָה מִלְחָמָה וְנוֹסַף גַּם־הוּא עַל־שֹׂנְאֵינוּ וְנִלְחַם־בָּנוּ וְעָלָה מִן־הָאָרֶץ
Come let us deal wisely with him. Lest he increase so much, that, if there is war, he will join our enemies and fight against us, driving us from the land.

Are there any commentaires or interpretations that say that this pasuk was spoken by the advisors of pharaoh and not pharaoh himself?

Comment: The Daas Zkenim says it was the King who said it. This is also the language of the pasuk before it. "And he said to his people".

Comment: Could you explain the question? Why would you think so?